# Finding the right Architectural pattern for flight search engine

Tags: java, architecture

I am working on a college project in Java. One of the first tasks we were given is to choose an Architectural pattern for our project (MVC, Repository, layers, etc) and create it visually.

I found a lot of different examples for Architectural patterns over the internet but I cant find anything that matches 100% the idea of the project. 
I also couldn't find an Architectural pattern example for a similar project (flight search engine system).

I'd appreciate any help finding the right Architectural pattern for the system we're creating in our project. Details about the system below:

Main functions: sign up, login, search, place an order, export reports for the travel agent/ agency as a whole.

Only a travel agent (with certificate) or a travel agent from a travelling agency can sign up to the system and use it. It is not possible for the passenger to use the system.
The agent can run a search. The results of the searches are pulled from a static JSON file (it is not a complex system, so it is not taking from real time database or something. We just shuffle the file every 2 hrs or so).
The search has different filters, including destination, origin country, number of passengers, one way or two and other non- mandatory fields.
The results are listed by best to worse ( pricing and shortest path). The algorithm to calculate the price is pretty simple and is based on airline company type (charter or scheduled flight, day in the week, season, holidays, etc).

If the customer (passenger) is interested in it, the travel agent can order it for him/her. An email with order details will be sent to the customer.The seats available on that ordered flight will be reduced accordingly and changed in the specific airline company file we allocated for it.

In addition, an export option is available for the agent to view all of the orders the made for all time and in specific dates as well. Cancellation is possible too.

That's it about the project,
I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I should consider changing the term **"architectural pattern"** into **architectural style**. Then, I should think about the fact that an architecture is a set of multiple architectural styles that are composed together into a system.

As I've said, you should choose multiple architectural style, not a single one, when designing a system. From the description posted by you I should use an **MVC** approach for the web layers: login, signup, place order, where I will use models, views and controllers. I suppose that you will read in detail about what is a model, a view and a controller.

Also, I will use a layered **ports-and-adapters/onion-architecture** style for a better decoupling of the code. Use adapters for interaction with external systems such as the database. Think in terms of **domain model** using **domain entities, aggregates and repositories**.

Good luck!